# rb-site install error: "Table 'reviewboard.auth_user' doesn't

Tags: review-board

I use yum install ReviewBoard to install successfully RB but when I run rb-site install, I get the final error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'reviewboard.auth_user' doesn't

Any idea on what Im missing? Thanks

Best regards,

XF

```
* Installing the site...
Building site directories ...
[!] Unable to find the Djblets media path. Make sure Djblets is
    installed and try this again.
OK
Building site configuration files ... OK
Creating database ...
[!] Unable to execute the manager command syncdb: cannot import name
    execute_manager

[!] Unable to execute the manager command registerscmtools: cannot
    import name execute_manager
OK
Performing migrations ...
[!] Unable to execute the manager command evolve: cannot import name
    execute_manager
OK
Creating administrator account ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rb-site", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ReviewBoard==1.7.27', 'console_scripts', 'rb-site')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 2170, in main
    command.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 1551, in run
    self.show_install_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 1864, in show_install_status
    site.create_admin_user)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 1011, in step
    func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/reviewboard/cmdline/rbsite.py", line 556, in create_admin_user
    self.admin_password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 195, in create_superuser
    **extra_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 186, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/models
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/backen
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/utils.
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/backen
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.8-py2.6.egg/django/db/backen
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in exe
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'reviewboard.auth_user' doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else have the same issue

I've downgraded django from 1.6.5 to 1.4.14
and that did the fix

```
//before you downgrade check the django version within python
python
import django
print django.VERSION


//to downgrade
easy_install django==1.4.14
```